# Export/Copy Attribute set from one Magentoinstall to another?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Using simple products in magento I Wish to copy a attributeset from one installation to a new one I'm setting up now. Is there a easier way than just recreate the set from the magento backend?

Comment: It is not very hard to recreate it in the new install is it?

Comment: @Lucasmus Depends how many you have.

Comment: Ended up recreating manualy in backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple, built-in mechanism for copying attribute/attribute-sets between installations in Magento. If it is too much work to copy manually, take a look at copying the tables that underly the attribute/sets themselves. A (possibly not exhaustive) list would be:

```
catalog_eav_attribute
eav_attribute
eav_attribute_set
```

You may have to reset your catalog (and lose anything that is in the target catalog) to use this method. Make sure to refresh indices and cache.

Another approach you could take would be to recreate the attributes programmatically (adding them as new attributes), but this will also be significant labor. Take a look at some of the tutorials on adding new attributes with a module installation for some code reference.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thank you, this is preget much what i expected.

Comment: Great idea, it's a shame Magento doesn't offer this function, it seems so easy.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget eav_attribute_group and eav_ebtity_attributes (magento 1.9x)!